# Ruby on Rails - prevent rails from creating session cookie until register

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

is there any method to prevent rails from creating a session cookie until user's have registered and opted in into using cookies? I didn't find any solution to my problem that's why I created a question here.

Comment: Couldn't you just add a checkbox to the form and then do a `before save` to verify it is checked by the person, and if not return a message?  With devise you should be able to set that up pretty easy in a user model (or whatever you are going to call the model).  What have you tried so far, any code you can share?

Comment: I want unregistered users to view my page as well, but due to GDPR compliance I can't until my cookies aren't disabled until the user agrees to use them.

Comment: Oh, sounds to me like you want a javascript solution that would show a window for them to comply, blocking the content until they do.  Again, any code you can show will help get to a solution faster.

Comment: I guess that won't fit my needs since I have a complete structure that relys on a registration. To give you some code - https://github.com/ziptofaf/gdpr-rails - that is the basic application.

Comment: But you just said you want unregistered users to view as well?

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked about the cookie disableing until a visitor is registered and opted in to use cookies.